# 3D rendering a still image on Javascript request

Tags: javascript, image, 3d, rendering

I am trying to make a service that needs to quickly render simple 3D scenes on the server, and then return them as a JPEG.

How could I request a job in HTML javascript?? Is it scalable for mass users and Would websockets do it?

```
function renderBlender(){
// 1. Send out a job
// ?? put something

// 2. Take result
// Get json and add it to HTML.
loadResult("Result.json");
//strImageList += "<a href=\"#\">";
//strImageList += "<img src='" + the location  + "' />";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special for this client-side. Your rendered-image is, client-side, undistinguishable from any server image. A simple `<img src="renderer.php?id=fa24da98">` should suffice. To make it ajaxy, you can set the image's src to the renderer's URL when needed.

Server-side is where all the magic lives. That is where you have to render the image (from whatever parameters the client sends you), and then return it inside a suitable HTTP response, using the correct headers.

Websockets will not help you in a single-request-per-client scenario; but they can make things much faster and lighter for a constant-stream-of-requests-per-client scenario. In that case, the above code

The scalability depends mostly on the server - load, hardware, webserver and how it is configured, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It kind of helped me what to look at.  Then, should I compose php or Java in a way that a ray tracer could be run in server all the time with input-parameter-single-request-per-client?

Comment: Yes. Just write a server program (be it java servlet or php script) that takes as input parameter something that describes what to generate, and returns the rendered image.